# Layout Designing - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I would like to know how to make this layout in android. I want to add 2 images for the 2 columns below and they are clickable.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? The drag and drop interface to make layouts isn't working?

Comment: I am trying Image Button as of the moment, I want to know the best way to do this

Comment: You might want to look at nested LinearLayouts or TableLayout

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Post the code you have so far. On a side note, this can be achieved in a lot of ways.

Comment: A single RelativeLayout will do the trick. Please avoid nesting layouts, since it's bad for performances. And a bad (unfortunately widely used) practice.

Comment: Please explain your issue with more details and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this i used a table layout to achieve your requirement.....In src you place your image from drawable...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="150dp" >

 <TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#c8c8c8" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/TextView04"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:background="#dcdcdc"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:padding="20dip"
 android:text="Row 2 column 1"
 android:textColor="#000000" 
 android:src="@drawable/swara"/>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/TextView04"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#d3d3d3"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="20dip"
android:text="Row 2 column 2"
android:textColor="#000000" 
android:src="@drawable/swara"/>  </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/upper_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/colourlayout"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might helpful.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <!-- Your code goes here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img_1"
            android:onclick="callFucntion1" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img_2"
            android:onclick="callFucntion2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, I think. Place your images in respective image layout elements.

```
android:src="........"
```

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="200"
    android:layout_above="@+id/colourlayout"
    >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/colourlayout"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

For clickable action you need to get the reference of the image by calling findviewbyID in java file.

example:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewbyID(R.id.image1);
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //code what should happen after clicking the image

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.